# Не могу подключить скрипты и стили в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Не понимаю в чем дело. Может, кто то подскажет? )

```
function irfas_scripts() {

    wp_register_style( 'irfas-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'irfas-style' );

    wp_register_style( 'font-avesome', get_stylesheet_uri() . 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css ' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-avesome' );

    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );


    wp_register_style( 'irfas-am-menu-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/am-menu.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'irfas-am-menu-style' );


    wp_register_style( 'irfas-main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'irfas-main-style' );

    wp_register_style( 'irfas-media-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/media.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'irfas-media-style' );


    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'irfas-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array(), 'false', false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'irfas-jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'irfas-am-menu-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/am-menu.js', array(), false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'irfas-am-menu-js' );

    wp_register_script( 'irfas-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'irfas-main-js' );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'irfas-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'irfas-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'irfas_scripts' );
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `get_stylesheet_uri()` использовать `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` если это дочерняя тема или `get_template_directory_uri()` если это родительская тема

Comment: Да спасибо, за помощь. В этом и была проблема. Правда я еще вчера об этом догадалась))))...

Comment: @eugene_v я бы вам предложил оформить это ответом, а автору вопроса - принять этот ответ. Ошибка типичная, думаю, ответ будет полезен.

Comment: Ага, я пробовал, с телефона это не удобно )) Почему-то на ios кнопка copy не копирует коммент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `get_stylesheet_uri()` использовать:

- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` - если это дочерняя тема;
- `get_template_directory_uri()` если это родительская тема;