# Проблема при работе WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ребят, прохожу уроки по WordPress, два дня пытаюсь найти ошибку не могу.
Стили не подключаются.
В консоль войти не могу, ошибка:

> Такой страницы не существует.

```
<?php 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','style_theme' );

function style_theme() {
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_enqueue_style('default', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/default.css');
wp_enqueue_style('layout', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/layout.css');
wp_enqueue_style('media-gueries', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/media-gueries.css');
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос не раз уже обсуждался здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907495/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81

Comment: Вы используете дочернюю тему?